# Powershell 2.0 broken Base64 file conversion

Tags: .net, powershell, base64, powershell-2.0

I found this code on https://mnaoumov.wordpress.com/2013/08/20/efficient-base64-conversion-in-powershell/

It works on windows 8.1 Powershell 4, but on Powershell 2 it seems to be adding a byte to the end of the file when I decode the base64 string back into the file. Powershell 2 also throws errors about the base64 string being an invalid length, but it still creates the file.

I have been trying to figure this out for hours but I don't know .net enough to figure out the issue.

I am using these functions to carry data is a larger script. It works without any errors on Powershell 4.

I need this to run on over 3000 windows 7 machines, sticking to Powershell 4 is not a solution.

```
function ConvertTo-Base64
{
    param
    (
        [string] $SourceFilePath,
        [string] $TargetFilePath
    )

    $SourceFilePath = Resolve-PathSafe $SourceFilePath
    $TargetFilePath = Resolve-PathSafe $TargetFilePath

    $bufferSize = 9000 # should be a multiplier of 3
    $buffer = New-Object byte[] $bufferSize

    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($SourceFilePath)
    $writer = [System.IO.File]::CreateText($TargetFilePath)

    $bytesRead = 0
    do
    {
        $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $bufferSize);
        $writer.Write([Convert]::ToBase64String($buffer, 0, $bytesRead));
    } while ($bytesRead -eq $bufferSize);

    $reader.Dispose()
    $writer.Dispose()
}

function ConvertFrom-Base64
{
    param
    (
        [string] $SourceFilePath,
        [string] $TargetFilePath
    )

    $SourceFilePath = Resolve-PathSafe $SourceFilePath
    $TargetFilePath = Resolve-PathSafe $TargetFilePath

    $bufferSize = 9000 # should be a multiplier of 4
    $buffer = New-Object char[] $bufferSize

    $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenText($SourceFilePath)
    $writer = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($TargetFilePath)

    $bytesRead = 0
    do
    {
        $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $bufferSize);
        $bytes = [Convert]::FromBase64CharArray($buffer, 0, $bytesRead);
        $writer.Write($bytes, 0, $bytes.Length);
    } while ($bytesRead -eq $bufferSize);

    $reader.Dispose()
    $writer.Dispose()
}

function Resolve-PathSafe
{
    param
    (
        [string] $Path
    )

    $ExecutionContext.SessionState.Path.GetUnresolvedProviderPathFromPSPath($Path)
}

ConvertTo-Base64 .\file .\Converted-File.txt
```

Comment: Does it add a byte to the end of the output file? Or to the original stream (resulting in a different Base64 string)?

Comment: It seems to be doubling the last byte on conversion from base64 to file.